Eccentric angle of ellipse
The eccentric angle of a point on the ellipse $x^2+3y^2=6$ at a distance of 2 units from the centre of the ellipse is
a: $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{4}$
b: $\frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}$
c: $\frac{\pi}{2}$
d: none
{My attempt} : By simplifying equation of ellipse will be $\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{2} =1$ here $a=\sqrt{6}$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$ so $a>b$ any point $p$ on ellipse is $a\cos(\theta),b\sin(\theta)...6\cos^2(\theta)+2\sin^2(\theta)=4$
$\cos(\theta)$ will be $\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}....$ I am looking for any direct formula if it exists for finding eccentric angle when such information given to us...Thanks in advance.

It's the first time I'm facing this kind of problem but I suppose that you could use what you've done and use the fact that the distance from the origin of your point $P$ on the ellipse has to be equal $2$
$$\sqrt{6\cos^2\theta + 2\sin^2\theta} = 2 \\
6\cos^2\theta + 2\sin^2\theta = 4 \\
6\cos^2\theta + 2 (1-\cos^2\theta) = 4 \\
cos^2\theta = \frac{1}{2} \iff \theta = \pm\frac{\pi}{4} + \pi k, \ k \in \Bbb Z$$
We can deduce a direct formula given ellipse's equation and distance $d$ of $P$ from the origin
$$\theta = \pm\arccos \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{d^2- b^2}{a^2-b^2}}\bigg) $$
for this case, if existence condition isn't respected we should take a similar approach and we end up with $(\arcsin)$.

While formula could be useful, personally I think that the approach "handy made" you've chosen it's much more worth.
Anyway I hope this helps!

@turquose thank you so much
